# mocking subprocess.Popen dependant on import style

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, subprocess, popen

When attempting to mock Popen I can only get it to succeed if the importing of subprocess matches in both unit test code and main module code.

Given following module listdir.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def listdir(dir):
    cmd = ['ls', dir]
    pc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = pc.communicate()
    if pc.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception
    return out
```

and following unit test code test_listdir.py

```
import subprocess
import listdir
import mock

@mock.patch.object(subprocess, 'Popen', autospec=True)
def test_listdir(mock_popen):
    mock_popen.return_value.returncode = 0
    mock_popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = ("output", "Error")
    listdir.listdir("/fake_dir")
```

For some reason Popen is not being mocked, due to the import style being different between the two python modules, and running the test always raises an exception.

If I change listdir.py to import all of subproces e.g.

```
import subprocess

def listdir(dir):
    cmd = ['ls', dir]
    pc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = pc.communicate()
    if pc.returncode != 0:
        raise ListingErrorException
    return out
```

Then "output" is returned in the test.

Anyone care to shed some light on why, my preference would be to have
from subprocess import Popen, Pipe in both modules, but I just can't get that to mock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to patch the copy of Popen in listdir, not the one you just imported.  So, instead of `@mock.patch.object(subprocess, 'Popen', autospec=True)`, try `@mock.patch.object(listdir, 'Popen', autospec=True)`

See this doc for more info: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch