# python unit testing mocking Popen and Popen.communicate

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to write a python unittest that does a subprocess call, so I'd like to mock that call.

I've already gone through these SO questions (to no avail):

- [Mocking a subprocess call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692440/mocking-a-subprocess-call-in-python)
- [mocking subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775969/mocking-subprocess-popen)
- [mocking subprocess.Popen dependant on import style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050888/mocking-subprocess-popen-dependant-on-import-style)
- [Mocking two functions with patch for a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763394/mocking-two-functions-with-patch-for-a-unit-test)

**benchmark.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def some_func():

  with Popen(some_list, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as process:

    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(timeout=timeout)
```

**test.py**

```
import mock

@mock.patch('benchmark.Popen.communicate')
@mock.patch('benchmark.Popen')
def test_some_func(self, mock_popen, mock_comm):

  mock_popen.return_value = 0
  mock_comm.return_value = ('output', 'error')

  foo = benchmark.some_func()
```

When running the unittest I get:

```
    stdout, stderr  = process.communicate(timeout=timeout)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

It looks like I'm not mocking the return value of `communicate` correctly;  what am I doing wrong?

### solution

I took the comments and suggested answers to solve things like this:

**test.py**

```
import mock

@mock.patch('benchmark.Popen')
def test_some_func(self, mock_popen):

  process = mock_popen.return_value.__enter__.return_value
  process.returncode = 0
  process.communicate.return_value = (b'some output', b'some error')

  foo = benchmark.some_func()
```

Comment: You need to mock the *context manager*, `process` will be `mock_popen.return_value.__enter__.return_value`.

Comment: I tried doing the same but i am getting below error :

AssertionError: <MagicMock name='Popen().wait()' id='139948711924680'> != 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jonrsharpe has mentioned, `with Popen(...) as process` is using `Popen` instance as a context manager, which calls `__enter__` method and assign its value to `process`.

jonsharpe's solution uses `return_value` magic of `mock` and it works fine. But you can also implement a context manager and wrap the mocking logic in it:

```
import mock
import subprocess


class MockedPopen:

    def __init__(self, args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.returncode = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def communicate(self, input=None, timeout=None):
        if self.args[0] == 'ls':
            stdout = '\n'.join(['hello.txt', 'world.txt'])
            stderr = ''
            self.returncode = 0
        else:
            stdout = ''
            stderr = 'unknown command'
            self.returncode = 1

        return stdout, stderr


@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen', MockedPopen)
def foo():
    with subprocess.Popen(['ls']) as proc:
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        print(stdout, stderr)


foo()
```

Output:

```
hello.txt
world.txt
```